# ListView без скролла Android Studio

Tags: listview

на странице вертикальный LinearLayout, в нем несколько TextView, последним идет ListView.
мне нужно чтобы скроллилась вся страница вместе с ListView, а он сам не скроллился бы потому что его полная высота не вписывается в экран, но он подгоняется под высоту экрана. 
Пробовал через добавление итемов адаптером в LinearLayout обернув все содержимое в ScrollView, работает, но не могу потом привязать onItemClickListener.

как отключить скролл у этого ListView?